# Marking a symbol as undefined in iOS framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, linker

I'm building an iOS framework using Swift and Objective-C (have to use both of them due to other constraints). 
In my objective-c code, I need to use a symbol, call it `MyUndefinedSymbol`, that will be available during runtime, but not during compile and link time.

I defined the symbol as `extern` to silence compiler errors:

`extern void MyUndefinedSymbol();`

However, linker complains that `MyUndefinedSymbol` is not defined.

Question is: how do I make the linker ignore that undefined symbol?

Searching for this brought me many solutions, none of them workd.
The things I tried:

1. Using the `-undefined` linker flag. It is deprecated and won't allow enabling bitcode (which I need).
2. Using clang's `-U` flag.
3. Adding a `weak_import` attribute using `__attribute__((weak_import))`
4. Using `--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all`.

Comment: Where does the symbol come from at runtime?

Comment: The framework (which is essentially a plugin) will be embedded by other applications which define this symbol. IOW, the symbol will be available at compile time of those applications, but not during the framework's compile time...

Comment: You could load it at runtime with `dlsym()` ...

Comment: @MartinR, I think this is exactly what I need! However, I couldn't get it to work. I was able to find and use a symbol that was part of the framework, but couldn't find the symbol that was part of the application that used the framework. Tried it with `RTLD_DEFAULT`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Is it defined as  a C or as a Swift function in the main executable?

Comment: It is a C function. I think the issue might be that the symbol I'm trying to find is statically linked into the application...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136049/discussion-between-martin-r-and-matanrubin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future readers:
Seems like the right way to do it is exactly as @Martin R suggested - using `dlsym()` to load the symbol at runtime.
Note that `dlsym` will not work on symbols which are marked as "Internal".
You can find out if a symbol is internal by running `nm -m` on your library/binary.

In addition, solutions 1 and 2 from the questions itself should work if you disable bitcode.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering this question. Unfortunately my situation is one where the symbol is internal (non-external)! Bah.